# How can I add Font Awesome support to Ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I am trying to add Font Awesome support to Ckeditor5-inline and it just removes the "i" tags from HTML when I go in Edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

First download font awesome if you haven't already then

```
 1. Extract the downloaded file (fontawesome.zip) Copy the "fontawesome"
 2. folder to "ckeditor/plugins/" folder Open the file
 3. "ckeditor/config.js"
```

configure that like this and clear your `browser's cache`

```
config.extraPlugins = 'fontawesome';
config.contentsCss = 'path/to/your/font-awesome.css';
config.allowedContent = true;
```

> In your HTML's  section add this code:

```
<script>CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false;</script>
```

after that you can Use `toolbargroupname: "FontAwesome"` in your toolbar like this

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'FontAwesome', 'Source' ] }
];
```

as you commented your are using Django  Integration in Django CMS

Django CMS enables adding text-based content to a site using `CKEditor` which is integrated through the module called `djangocms_text_ckeditor`. In that module is a static folder and settings.py file, which are setup in a manner that enables fully customizing `CKEditor`.

[you can check here for Django Integration](http://www.diehlworks.com/en/blog/customize-ckeditor-in-django-cms/)

Comment: I am actually trying to add font awesome into ckeditor in Django CMS. So basically I will build the ckeditor and then add the js file to my project. Is there a way to configure the project and get all the font awesome info in that js file?